# Animation handling through CSS and jQuery .css() method differences

Tags: jquery, css, performance, animation

Is there a particular performance downside on handling animations (changing transition values for example) using jQuery .css() method rather than doing it straight in CSS?

Comment: Well, `.css()` and `.animate()` edit inline styles, while CSS style sheets are separate from the dom. Editing the dom quickly can cause thrashing (lag from the browser trying to repaint quickly). Therefore I say putting css animations in style sheets is better.

Comment: I don't think so. jQuery writes inline <style> tags, so it would be the same as you wrote those yourself. jQuery might take a little time to update the dom, but other than that I think they're equivalent. If you have a way of doing what you're trying to do with pure css, use css.

Comment: Wait, are we talking about the same thing? .css updates the dom once, while .animate does it many times, right?

Comment: But if animation is done with .css by changing, let's say left:0px; to left:100px;, then the repositioning of the element is done by CSS and jQuery did execute the code only once, right? Whereas with .animate the element would have been repositioned by 100px firing the step function internally 100 times. If that's the case then if this is scaled up, jQuery would get a lot of firing events which could be done by CSS, so handling animation straight through CSS would be better.

Comment: The difference in using `.css` and a CSS file does side with using just CSS, but the difference is minimal. The *only* difference in run time is the time it takes to run the jQuery, turn it into js, then add the styles which takes ***very*** little time. However if `.css` is the only or one of few reasons for jQuery, the size of jQuery itself is the reason why it should be avoided

Comment: Another reason I find using pure css being very useful, is that by using the "animation" css property you can add predefined keyframes to it, giving more flexibility to the way you handle an animation, allowing to set by percentages for example  "from 0% to 20% of the duration of the animation , do any kind of css properties to an element", it reduces javascript or jquery code a lot by handling through classes adding or removing them. I also believe that in a group of persons that works on the same software, maintainability is also a concern when writing code for animations.